# upgrade to 20.04 failed - unmet dependencies, held packages

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dependencies

Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 failed in the middle (just quit) and left a mess. The OS is still on 18.04 and I'm trying to revert back to bionic

**Question**: How do I resolve the *held packages* and *unmet dependencies* issues?

**Details**

sources.list showed focal so I changed that back to bionic

```
root@core:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                       
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                             
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

But when I attempt to upgrade

```
    root@core:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     alacarte : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     appmenu-qt : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8) but it is not installed
     arandr : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     compizconfig-settings-manager : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                                     Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
     freecad : Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
               Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     gimp : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     google-musicmanager-beta : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
                                Depends: libqtwebkit4 but it is not installed
     hamster-applet : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                      Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
     hamster-indicator : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                         Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
     ibus-pinyin : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     inkscape : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     itstool : Depends: python but it is not installed
     kde-style-breeze-qt4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     kdelibs-bin : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     kdoctools : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libattica0.4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
     libbaloocore4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libbaloofiles4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libbalooxapian4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
     libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
     libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
     libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
     libdbusmenu-qt2 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
     libkactivities6 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
     libkcalcore4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8) but it is not installed
     libkcmutils4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkde3support4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkdeclarative5 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkdecore5 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkdesu5 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkdeui5 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkdewebkit5 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libqtwebkit4 but it is not installed
     libkdnssd4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkemoticons4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     libkf5auth5 : Depends: libkf5authcore5 (= 5.68.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 is installed
     libkf5configwidgets5 : Depends: libkf5configwidgets-data (= 5.44.0-0ubuntu1) but 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
     libkf5declarative5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 is installed
is installed
     mercurial : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                 Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not installed
                 Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
     mercurial-common : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                        Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     nautilus-dropbox : Depends: python:any
     ntfs-config : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                   Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
     onboard : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     openssh-sftp-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3)
     phonon-backend-gstreamer : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.1) but it is not installed
     plasma-scriptengine-javascript : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
     puddletag : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     pyside-tools : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                    Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                    Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
     python-acoustid : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     python-appindicator : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                           Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                           Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
     python-apt : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                  Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not installed
                  Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     python-aptdaemon : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                        Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
     python-libxml2 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                      Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not installed
                      Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                      Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     python-zope.interface : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                             Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not installed
                             Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
               Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
     python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8.0-1~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-protobuf : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-renderpm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     python3-venv : Depends: python3 (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
     qdbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not installed
     qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.8+dfsg~) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 is installed
     qml-module-qtqml-models2 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 is installed
     samba : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
             Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not installed
             Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
             Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.3 is installed
             Recommends: attr
             Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not installed
     samba-common-bin : Depends: python but it is not installed
                        Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.3 is installed
     samba-dsdb-modules : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.3 is installed
                          Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.3 is installed
     samba-libs : Depends: libldb2 (>= 2:2.0.10~) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python3-talloc (>= 2.2.0~) but it is not installable
     smbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17) but 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.3 is installed
     sni-qt : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.3-1ubuntu3~) but it is not installed
     solaar : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     steam-launcher : Depends: python but it is not installed
     supervisor : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
     ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python but it is not installed
     ubuntu-sso-client-qt : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                            Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
     ubuntuone-client : Depends: python but it is not installed
                        Recommends: ubuntu-sso-client-gui (>= 4.1)
     ubuntuone-control-panel : Depends: python but it is not installed
     ubuntuone-control-panel-qt : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                                  Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
     v4l2ucp : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
     webmin : Depends: python but it is not installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

(many lines deleted so it would fit)

and trying to fix broken installs produces:

```
root@core:~# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alacarte : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
```

The same long list of unmet dependencies.

```
webmin : Depends: python but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: I've release-upgraded many machines over the years and I've never seen a "failed in the middle (just quit)." Are you *sure* there was no error message? No poweroff? Nothing else we need to know?

Answer (score 2):

A release-upgrade failure might be recoverable...but it might not. A release-upgrade is a brief interval when your system is most vulnerable. Depends upon where in the process the interruption occurred.

If your system was downloading (not installing), then the release-upgrade can usually be resumed.

- Change your sources to 'focal'
- Run `sudo apt update`
- If it completes without error, then run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
- If it completes without error, then run `sudo apt autoremove`. Read your output carefully before agreeing to autoremoval.

Some errors are recoverable. Some are not, and require a reinstall of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
  sudo apt update had errors with focal but none with bionic
  Neither sudo apt upgrade or sudo apt dist-upgrade would run without error.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting contents of /var/lib/dpkg/status provided some relief to the problems with apt and enabled some progress but I was concerned about stability and ability to upgrade.
Finally cut my losses and installed 20.04 over the top of 18.04